# Vue does not display pass parameters to child vue

Tags: vue.js

Hi i have 2 simples vues i want to pass properties from the parent to child but i have empty display ( just the logo and no firstname, lastname and from param )

a parent App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <Hello firstname='John' lastname='Doe' from='New York' img='/src/assets/logo.png'/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello
  }
}
</script>
```

and a hello.vu:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="img">
    <h1> Hello {{ firstname }} {{ lastname }} de {{ from }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {

  },
  props: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'from']
}
</script>
```

I check twice the syntax, seems all fine for me, don't know why it just display non texts

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the data, not just pass it as attributes. Therefore this:

```
<Hello firstname='John' lastname='Doe' from='New York' img='/src/assets/logo.png'/>
```

should be this:

```
<Hello :firstname="'John'" :lastname="'Doe'" :from="'New York'" :img="'/src/assets/logo.png'"/>
```

Think of the colon `:` as prefix to make the attribute into a prop. Whatever is inside the double quotes is evaluated as JavaScript, so you have to pass in a string in single quotes in order for it to be recognized as a string and not a variable.

Ideally you'd do this instead:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <Hello :firstname="firstName" :lastname="lastName" :from="location" :img="image"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello.vue'
import logo from './assets/logo.png'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello
  },
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      location: 'New York',
      image: logo
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

A thing to notice is that there are no longer single quotes around the bound values, and that's because they're no longer strings but rather variables coming from the data object which contain strings. Keep your content separate from your code's logic always. You'll find maintaining your code much easier. We're also now importing the image asset and passing it as a variable to the component via the data object.

Comment: Thanks for you comments, i think that the original problem above is coming from the img binding, i have the error: TyeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'img' in undefined

Comment: You should only put mutable properties in data. Constants are better placed in the computed section or as instance properties.

Comment: Respectfully disagree with the above. Computed properties (which are cached) and methods (which are not cached) should be used when you need to modify data before consuming it in your template.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bind values when sending strings as props.

**Solution**: just change single `'` to double `"`

```
-  <Hello firstname='John' lastname='Doe' from='New York' img='/src/assets/logo.png'/>
+  <Hello firstname="John" lastname="Doe" from="New York" img="/src/assets/logo.png"/>
```

**Extra Note:**

Vue works like this:

```js
<some-component userName="John" name="title" />
```

If in SomeComponent you specify props `userName` and `name`:

```js
{
  ...,
  props: ['userName', 'name'],
  ...,
}
```

Data will be treated as props. In this case string "John" and string "title". Vue is that smart enought ;-)

But if you don't, Vue will add `userName` and `name` as properties to `$attrs` object.

Comment: My mistake on the passing of strings without binding.

Comment: Like I said. If you want to send string, you don't have to bind it. You can do `<some-component userName="John" />` There is no need for: `<some-component :userName="'John'" />`